# SQL employee / company/country

Tags: sql

I have three tables

1. Country (country id - country name - country pop)
2. City (city id - city name - city code - city pop)
3. Company (city code - company name - company employee) 
   Company employee is the number of employee.

I must present a table with the  SUM of the employees that has each company in country level.

I have used the following query

```
SELECT country_name, company_name, company_employee  
FROM country,
     city,
     company
WHERE country.country_id = city.country_id
  and city.city_code = company.city_code
```

I took a table in which you can see the country, the company and the number of employee 
(e.g. In one country UK the same company ACS  has 2 records ACS 300 EMPLOYEE & ACS 100 EMPLOYEE instead of one record ACS 400 employee)

I believe that something is missing from my code. I have tried use functions such as  sum and group but it failed.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: It's good programming practice to always qualify all columns when several tables are involved. E.g. `country.country_name` instead of just `country_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT cy.country_name, co.company_name, SUM(co.company_employee)  
FROM company co JOIN
     city ci
     ON ci.city_code = co.city_code JOIN
     country cy
     ON cy.country_id = ci.country_id
GROUP BY cy.country_name, co.company_name;
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, modern, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  This is particularly important if you are learning SQL; you should  learn to use the language correctly.